# MySQL error for 2 tables cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create 2 tables in the same database. however it still cannot create foreign key.

```
 create table countryadrc
 (
adrc char(3) not null,
county varchar(30) not null,
primary key (adrc),
unique (adrc, county)
 );
```

it is the other table which observe the error

```
create table localities
(
county varchar(30) not null,
locality tinyint not null,
primary key (county),
foreign key (county) references countryadrc (county)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema seems to be a little strange but you can technically make it work if you swap columns in `UNIQUE` constraint in `countryadrc` table.

> [Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)
>   ... In the referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
>   columns are listed as **the first columns** in the same order ...

```
create table countryadrc
(
  adrc char(3) not null,
  county varchar(30) not null,
  primary key (adrc),
  unique (county, adrc) -- county should be the leftmost column in the index
);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50cc0)** demo

Comment: thank you for your help. i know my 2 two have a little strange. my condition is adrc-->county and county --> locality. when i want to meet the requirement of 3NF, i have done this. Can you give me some advices?

Comment: To give you any meaningful advice I need to know much more about what are you're trying to model. What is `adrc`? First table called `countryadrc` but FK column in `localities` is called `county` (without R)? What are relations? ...etc. Here is another thing: using natural keys is OK on its own but might be impractical when using InnoDB Engine. With InnoDB you want to have as small PK as possible because it will be included in any secondary key in the table. Thus it leaves you with the choice of using surrogate `INT` PK. It's not necessary but at least it's something you want to think about.